# Developer Assignment - Family Tree

Tags: java, beginner

I have an alternative solution for family tree that have been posted some time ago and please forgive the similarity of the task but when i tried to post alternative solution in someone else's post and asked for review I got deleted.

Model the family tree such that:

```
Input:
    Person=Alex Relation=Brothers
Expected Output should be
    Brothers=John,Joe

Input:
    Husband=Bern Wife=Julia
Expected Output should be
    Welcome to the family, Julia
```

List of supported relations:

```
Father
Mother
Brother(s)
Sister(s)
Son(s)
Daughter(s)
Sibling
```

Assumption:

- Names are unique. Any new member added will also have a unique name.

#### TreeApp

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TreeApp {

    public static Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
    public static RelationshipFactory rl = new RelationshipFactory();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Boolean quit = false;

        printMenu();
        try{
            while(!quit){
                System.out.println("Enter option:");
                int operation = sc.nextInt();
                sc.nextLine();
                switch(operation){
                    case 1:
                        System.out.println("Menu:");
                        printMenu();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        rl.printFamilyMap();
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        System.out.println("Enter query");
                        proceedWithQuerry();
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        System.out.println("Fill with test data");
                        rl.populateFamilyTree();
                        break;
                    default:
                        System.out.println("QUIT");
                        quit = true;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error while getting option - quit");
        }
    }

    private static void proceedWithQuerry() {
        String query = sc.nextLine();
        QueryParser qp = new QueryParser();
        qp = qp.parse(query);
        if (qp.com.equals(Command.ADD)){
            rl.addRelation(qp.p1,qp.rel2,qp.p2,qp.rel1,0);
        } else if (qp.com.equals(Command.RETRIEVE)){
            rl.getSiblings(qp);
        } else{
            System.out.println("Process terminated");
        }
    }

    private static void printMenu() {
        System.out.println("1 - Print menu,"
                + "\n2 - Print familyTree,"
                + "\n3 - Enter query,"
                + "\n4 - Inject test data.");
    }
}
```

#### RelationshipFactory

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class RelationshipFactory {

    private static Map<String,HashMap<String,Relation>> familyMap = new HashMap<>();

    public RelationshipFactory() {
    }

    public void addRelation(String p1, Relation rel1, String p2, Relation rel2, int mode){

        HashMap<String, Relation> personalMap = new HashMap<>();

        if (familyMap.get(p1) == null){
            personalMap.put(p2, rel1);
            familyMap.put(p1, personalMap);
            System.out.println("Welcome to the family, " + p1 );
        } else {
            personalMap = familyMap.get(p1);
            if (personalMap.get(p2) == null){
                personalMap.put(p2, rel1);
            }
        }
        if (mode == 0){
            addRelation(p2, rel2, p1, rel1, 1);
        }
    }

    public void printFamilyMap(){

        System.out.println("Family Tree:\n");

        for (Map.Entry<String,HashMap<String,Relation>> entry : familyMap.entrySet()){
            System.out.println("Person: " + entry.getKey() + ":");
            entry.getValue().forEach((p,role) -> { System.out.println("\t\t\t" + p + " - " + role.toString());});
        }
    }

    public void getSiblings(QueryParser qp) {
        Boolean foundMember = false;
        if (familyMap.get(qp.p1) == null) System.out.println("Unregonised member of the family.");
        else { 
            System.out.println(qp.rel2 + ": ");
            for (Map.Entry<String,Relation> entry : familyMap.get(qp.p1).entrySet()){
                if (entry.getValue().equals(qp.rel2)){
                    System.out.println("\t\t\t" + entry.getKey());
                    foundMember = true;
                }
            }
            if (!foundMember) System.out.println("\tnot found."  );
        }
    }

    public void populateFamilyTree() {
        addRelation("Bern", Relation.WIFE, "Julia", Relation.HUSBAND, 0); 
        addRelation("Bern", Relation.SON, "Boris", Relation.FATHER, 0);
        addRelation("Bern", Relation.SON, "Adam", Relation.FATHER, 0);
        addRelation("Bern", Relation.DAUGHTER, "Zoe", Relation.FATHER, 0);
        addRelation("Julia", Relation.SON, "Adam", Relation.MOTHER, 0);
        addRelation("Julia", Relation.SON, "Boris", Relation.MOTHER, 0);
        addRelation("Julia", Relation.DAUGHTER, "Zoe", Relation.MOTHER, 0);
        addRelation("Julia", Relation.SISTER, "Alicia", Relation.SISTER, 0);
        addRelation("Bern", Relation.SIBLING, "Alicia", Relation.SIBLING, 0);
    }
}
```

#### QueryParser

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

enum Command {ADD, RETRIEVE, ERROR}
enum Relation {MOTHER, FATHER, SON, DAUGHTER, BROTHER, SISTER, WIFE, HUSBAND, SIBLING};

public class QueryParser {

    /*
        Person=Bern Relation=Wife
        Mother=Julia Son=Boris
    */

    Command com; 
    String p1;
    String p2;
    Relation rel1;
    Relation rel2;

    public QueryParser() {
    }

    public QueryParser(Command com, String p1, String p2, Relation rel1, Relation rel2) {
        this.com = com;
        this.p1 = p1;
        this.p2 = p2;
        this.rel1 = rel1;
        this.rel2 = rel2;
    }

    public QueryParser parse(String query) {
        List<String> list = Stream.of(query.split("[ =]+")).map(elem -> new String(elem)).collect(Collectors.toList());
        if (list.size()!=4) {
            System.out.println("Error while parsing to list");
            com = Command.ERROR;
        } else if (list.get(0).equals("Person")){
            com = Command.RETRIEVE;
            p1 = list.get(1);
            rel2 = adjustRelation(list.get(3));
        } else {
            com = Command.ADD;
            p1 = list.get(1);
            p2 = list.get(3);
            rel1 = adjustRelation(list.get(0));
            rel2 = adjustRelation(list.get(2)); 
        }

    return new QueryParser(com,p1,p2,rel1,rel2);
    }

    private Relation adjustRelation(String rel){
        switch(rel){
            case "Mother":
                return Relation.MOTHER;
            case "Father":
                return Relation.FATHER;
            case "Husband":
                return Relation.HUSBAND;
            case "Wife":
                return Relation.WIFE;
            case "Son":
                return Relation.SON;
            case "Sons":
                return Relation.SON;
            case "Daughters":
                return Relation.DAUGHTER;
            case "Daughter":
                return Relation.DAUGHTER;
            case "Sisters":
                return Relation.SISTER;
            case "Sister":
                return Relation.SISTER;
            case "Brother":
                return Relation.BROTHER;
            case "Brothers":
                return Relation.BROTHER;
            default:
                return Relation.SIBLING;
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### QueryParser

Right now your query parser has two responsibilities. It parses the query (hence its name), but it also contains the result of the parse, which is kind of unintuitive and violates the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

I'd create a `Query` class that would contain the members `com, p1, p2, rel1, rel2`.

If you're not already confortable with polymorphism, I'd try using it to create `ErrorCommand`, `RetrieveCommand` and `AddCommand` instead of just a `Query` class. You could use the `Command` pattern to separate the responsibilities instead of using the `if/else if/else` from the `proceedWithQuerry` method.

#### RelationshipFactory

This class isn't really a [Factory Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern). In this situation I think you should try to rename it to something else. The only method in the class that kind of fits a `Factory` is the `populateFamilyTree` method. You could check out the [Builder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) pattern to help build your family tree. It could be an interesting exercise though some people might argue that it's overkill. But as you tagged your question as `beginner`, I feel like you could learn something from trying to implement this :)

The `int mode` parameter to `addRelation` isn't intuitive. I think that it is used to "mirror" the relationship (so that `Sibling(Harry,Emma)` would also add `Sibling(Emma,Harry)`), this should be made clearer.

#### TreeApp

If I'm using your application, how can I know what I'm supposed to enter when this is prompted : `System.out.println("Enter option:");`. You should print the options with what they do so that users can use your application.

#### General

The variable names should be more explicit. Looking at this : `String p1;`, how can I know what it will contain? Naming it `firstPerson` or something of the like would be good. Short variable names bring nothing of value, especially with IDEs.